# Make a button go to a link selected in form select

Tags: jquery, html, forms, html-select

This is the piece of code in question:

```
<form>
    <select name="someoptions">
        <option value="page1.html">Page 1</option>
        <option value="page2.html">Page 2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="buttontheme">
</form>
```

I found this link on stackoverflow: [Open a link via a button press chosen from a form select option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076130/open-a-link-via-a-button-press-chosen-from-a-form-select-option)

But the selected answer doesn't explain where to put the piece of code or how to use it in the html page. Can anyone walk me through on how to make this happen? Thank you

So far I have this as a test.html without any other files:

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script> 
    $('#select-id').change(function() {
   url = $('#select-id').val();
   window.open(url);
});
    </script>
    <script> 

</script>

</head>

<body>

<form>
    <select id="select-id" name="someoptions">
        <option value="https://magecomp.com/blog/how-to-install-magento-2-on-windows-on-xampp-server-with-git/">Page 1</option>
        <option value="https://magecomp.com/blog/how-to-install-magento-2-on-windows-on-xampp-server-with-git/">Page 2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="buttontheme">
</form>

</body>
```

When I select an option and then click on the Submit button, it takes me from:

[file:///C:/Users/eyeglasses/Desktop/Website/test.html](http://file:///C:/Users/cubicle2/Desktop/K/Website/Norwell/test.html)

to

[file:///C:/Users/eyeglasses/Desktop/Website/test.html?someoptions=https%3A%2F%2F‌​magecomp.com%2Fblog%2Fhow-to-install-magento-2-on-windows-on-xampp-server-with-gi‌​t%2F](http://file:///C:/Users/eyeglasses/Desktop/Website/test.html?someoptions=https%3A%2F%2F%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bmagecomp.com%2Fblog%2Fhow-to-install-magento-2-on-windows-on-xampp-server-with-gi%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bt%2F)

and doesn't do anything or change the page (I still see the dropdown menu and Submit button).

Answer (score 0):

```
    <form>
        <select id="select-id" name="someoptions">
            <option value="page1.html">Page 1</option>
            <option value="page2.html">Page 2</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="buttontheme">
    </form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script> 
    $('#select-id').change(function() {
       url = $('#select-id').val();
       window.open(url);
    });
    </script>
```

You have to include the jquery library in your head of html to make it run.window.open is a function of javascript that opens url in browser. You have to pass the url to function window.open in order to get required result. Working on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/phzgLtfs/1/)

Comment: This wouldn't work, you're applying a eventListener to a button element, but the form has an input as submit button.

Comment: sorry i hadn't noticed my code. I had made this correct Please review this.

Comment: Still missing the hash-tag before the id

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I created a minimal test.html page with just the script here pasted in between the <head> tags and the rest of the form in between the <body> tags, and I replaced the links with google.com and yahoo.com but it doesn't go to those websites. Instead when I click the Submit button, it stays on the same page

Comment: had you included  the jquery library file in head section of html?

Comment: Yes, I put <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> in the head section, and my jquery-1.11.1.min.js file is in the same directory as my test.html file. Also it is not working in Fiddle. When I click the button, it says {"error": "Please use POST request"}

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/phzgLtfs/5/ check its working like charms . are you nut man.

Comment: I tried that Fiddle on two different browsers (Firefox and Chrome). Clicking the Submit button does no action on both

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/phzgLtfs/8/ try this .I had correct the url in select list sorry for that.

Comment: When I click on the Submit button of my test.html, it goes to the link: file:///C:/Users/eyeglasses/Desktop/Website/test.html?someoptions=https%3A%2F%2Fmagecomp.com%2Fblog%2Fhow-to-install-magento-2-on-windows-on-xampp-server-with-git%2F

Comment: I will add the exact code I have in my original post

Answer (score 0):

The code provided in your link just registers the click even to any button on the page. This would be a better solution:

```
<form id="goToPageForm">
    <select name="page">
        <option value="page1.html">Page 1</option>
        <option value="page2.html">Page 2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="buttontheme" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#goToPageForm').submit(function(e) {
        document.location = $(this).find('[name="page"]').val();

        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Regardless of how the form is submitted (i.e. by enter press of by clicking the submit button), the browser is being redirected to the selected page.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I created a minimal test.html page with just the script here pasted in between the <head> tags and the rest of the form in between the <body> tags, and I replaced the links with google.com and yahoo.com but it doesn't go to those websites. Instead when I click the Submit button, it stays on the same page

Comment: The script doesn't go in head-tag, just leave it in this order in the body of your page. https://jsfiddle.net/5ctfgxc6/

Comment: I don't understand why this isn't working. I copied and pasted your code exactly in a test.html page, and changed the option values to http://www.google.com/ and http://www.yahoo.com/ but when I select for example the Google option then click on Submit, the page doesn't do anything and the URL in the address bar displays: file:///C:/Users/eyeglasses/Desktop/Website/test.html?page=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F